# Extending Class via Multiple Private Inheritance - Is this a thing?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to encapsulate existing functionality in a wide swathe of classes so it can be uniformly modified (e.g. mutexed, optimized, logged, etc.)  For some reason, I've gotten it into my head that (multiple) private inheritance is the way to go, but I can't find what led me to that conclusion.

The question is: what is the name for what I am trying to do, and where I can see it done right?

What I think this isn't:

- Decorator: All the descriptions I see for this pattern wrap a class to provide extra methods as viewed from the outside. I want to provide functionality to the inside (extract existing as well as add additional.)
- Interface: This is close, because the functionality has a well-defined interface (and one I would like to mock for testing.) But again this pattern deals with the view from the outside.

I'm also open to alternatives, but the jackpot here is finding an article on it written by someone much smarter than me (a la Alexandrescu, Meyers, Sutter, etc.)

Example code:

```
// Original code, this stuff is all over
class SprinkledFunctionality
{
  void doSomething()
  {
    ...
    int id = 42;
    Db* pDb = Db::getDbInstance(); // This should be a reference or have a ptr check IRL
    Thing* pThing = pDb->getAThing(id);
    ...
  }
}

// The desired functionality has been extracted into a method, so that's good
class ExtractedFunctionality
{
  void doSomething()
  {
    ...
    int id = 42;
    Thing* pThing = getAThing(id);
    ...
  }

protected:
  Thing* getAThing(int id)
  {
    Db* pDb = Db::getDbInstance();
    return pDb->getAThing(id);
  }
}

// What I'm trying to do, or want to emulate
class InheritedFunctionality : private DbAccessor
{
  void doSomething()
  {
    ...
    int id = 42;
    Thing* pThing = getAThing(id);
    ...
  }
}

// Now modifying this affects everyone who accesses the DB, which is even better
class DbAccessor
{
public:
  Thing* getAThing(int id)
  {
    // Mutexing the DB access here would save a lot of effort and can't be forgotten
    std::cout << "Getting thing #" << id << std::endl; // Logging is easier
    Db* pDb = Db::getDbInstance(); // This can now be a ptr check in one place instead of 100+
    return = pDb->getAThing(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One useful technique you might be overlooking is the non-virtual interface (NVI) as coined by Sutter in his writings about virtuality. It requires a slight inversion of the way you're looking at it, but is intended to address those precise concerns. It also tackles those concerns from within as opposed, to say, decorator which is about extending functionality non-intrusively from the outside.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void something()
    {
        // can add all the central code you want here for logging,
        // mutex locking/unlocking, instrumentation, etc.
        ...
        impl_something();
        ...
    }

private:
    virtual void impl_something() = 0;
};
```

The idea is to favor non-virtual functions for your public interfaces, but make them call virtual functions (with private or protected access) which are overridden elsewhere. This gives you both the extensibility you typically get with inheritance while retaining central control (something otherwise often lost).

Now `Bar` can derive from `Foo` and override `impl_something` to provide specific behavior. Yet you retain the central control in `Foo` to add whatever you like and affect all subclasses in the `Foo` hierarchy.

Initially `Foo::something` might not even do anything more than call `Foo::impl_something`, but the value here is the breathing room that provides in the future to add any central code you want -- something which can otherwise be very awkward if you're looking down at a codebase which has a boatload of dependencies directly to virtual functions. By depending on a public non-virtual function which depends on an overridden, non-public virtual function, we gain an intermediary site to which we can add all the central code we like.

Note that this can be overkill too. Everything can be overkill in SE, as a simple enough program might actually be the easiest to maintain if it just used global variables and a big `main` function. All of these techniques have trade-offs, but the pros begin to outweigh the cons with sufficient scale, complexity, changing requirements*.

<sub>* *I noticed in one of your other questions that you wrote that the right tool for the job should have zero drawbacks, but everything tends to have drawbacks, everything is a trade-off. It's whether the pros outweigh the cons that ultimately determines whether it was a good design decision, and it's far from easy to realize all of this in foresight instead of hindsight.*</sub>

As for your example:

```
// What I'm trying to do, or want to emulate
class InheritedFunctionality : private DbAccessor
{
  void doSomething()
  {
    ...
    int id = 42;
    Thing* pThing = getAThing(id);
    ...
  }
}
```

... there is a significantly tighter coupling here than is necessary for this example. There might be more to it than you've shown which makes private inheritance a necessity, but otherwise composition would generally loosen the coupling considerably without much extra effort, like so:

```
class ComposedFunctionality
{
  ...
  void doSomething()
  {
    ...
    int id = 42;
    Thing* pThing = dbAccessor.getAThing(id);
    ...
  }
  ...

private:
  DbAccessor dbAccessor;
};
```

Comment: Coupling is probably appropriate for some of it, but some of functionality includes a public interface.  Take logging, where anything that logs should also allow client code to modify its logging level.  Using composition would necessitate implementing a public method to modify the logger member in all classes that aren't in the same family.

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus Similar issue applies for private inheritance. We can't inherit a method to control logging level and expose it publicly unless we inherit publicly, use a forwarding function, or `using`. Both private inheritance and composition would hide such details away from the public interface of the class which uses either composition or private inheritance. Here it might be a benefit though to accept the tighter coupling just to retain that `using` declaration for class members as opposed to a forwarding function.

Comment: You're right, of course private inheritance alone won't add a public interface, not sure what I was thinking.  Technically public inheritance would probably be ok, since it "is-a" Loggable or DbAccessor, but private seemed safer.

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus Does the cited NVI idiom potentially help for this case? If so, you could add a public method to the class with the non-virtual interface which sets logging level, e.g., while retaining the ability to extend it all you like with subclasses that do whatever you want in between the logging and other stuff you do centrally for a family of related classes.

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus The way I'm diagnosing your situation (possibly not fully correctly) is that you have a need to have central control over an area of code in a way where you can change it once and affect a bunch of things. But all these things do something differently in between that central code. There NVI can really hit the spot -- it lets you extend/override what to do in between the central code, but also lets you keep that central control and without writing/maintaining too much code on the way.

Comment: That's mostly right.  We're using NVI in other places, but it seems to be more geared towards when you have a process outline with differing implementation details.  Two of these things could have logging calls in wildly different places, and drastically different internal structures.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're doing is decoupling the way you `getAThing` from the way you `doSomething`. Looks a lot like the Factory Method object-oriented design pattern. Have a look here:
[Factory Method Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html)

Comment: So in terms of this pattern, I'm making things that need a DB become a DB factory for themselves? The explanation doesn't feel right, esp. coupled with the focus on the creation/factory aspect.The technical solution is very close, but there's a disconnect in the language that makes me wary.  In my experience, if the concept and the execution don't agree, one or more of them is wrong.